# Multiple Inheritance ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, multiple-inheritance

I'm creating a game and for this I've created several base classes that can be used server side and client side such as Troop and Infantry (extends Troop). The infantry class implements methods such as isInfantry.

To create client side rendering I've created a class called TroopClient that extends Troop and adds to its attributes a sprite and a method to move such sprite. Afterwards I've created InfantryClient that extends TroopClient. Now this InfantryClient has sprites attributes and methods but doenst implement the Infantry methods.

I have looked into mix ins but I haven't found a good article with ES6 classes and I don't know if my approach is right.

I'm looking for some insight regarding this problem and how to use mix ins (If it's a good approach) to do just that (with some explanation).

Comment: For things like making an object render-able traits/mixins or composition are a better solution then inheritance. The relation `TroopClient` and `Troop` is questionable anyway. One befit of JS is that existing Classes and Objects can be extended without inheritance.

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance as described in [this fun-fun video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA)

Comment: Why is the inherit relation questionable? It seems to me that is very natural as I want to extend the behavior of the parent Class and making it more specific.

Comment: Yeah that video shows the usual messed up examples of why inheritance doesn't work. But I really don't like to use composition as, in my opinion, the code gets less readable and understandable.

Comment: @gazdagergo fun-fun got composition completely, entirely wrong, and actual composition never once made an appearance in that video. https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/5dxq6i/composition_over_inheritance/da8bplv/

Answer (score 1):

ES6 or any other ES/JS version doesn't support multiple inheritance or mixins. Since it's a dynamically typed language, you can mimic the behaviour but that will have some limitation and downsides. You may want to check some [examples](http://justinfagnani.com/2015/12/21/real-mixins-with-javascript-classes/) [online](https://javascript.info/mixins) for workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I've used to allow multiple inheritence in JS. Though your milage may vary.

```js
var custom = function() {
 
 "use strict";
 
 return {
  class: function(constructor,prototype) {
   constructor.prototype = prototype;
   return constructor;
  },
  
  class_extends: function(bases,constructor,prototype) {
   for (var i = 0; i < bases.length; ++i) {
    var base = bases[i];
    
    for (var property in base.prototype) {
     if (!prototype[property]) {
      prototype[property] = base.prototype[property];
     }
    }
   }
   
   function bundledConstructor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < bases.length; ++i) {
     bases[i].apply(this,arguments);
    }
    
    constructor.apply(this,arguments);
   }
   
   constructor.prototype = prototype;
   bundledConstructor.prototype = prototype;
   
   return bundledConstructor;
  }
 };
 
}();

void function() {
 
 "use strict";
 
 var Base_1 = custom.class(
  // Constructor function
  function() {
   
  },
  
  // Prototype, shared between class instances
  // use for constant values & functions
  {
   overloadedFunction: function() {
    console.log("This is from base 1");
   },
   
   base_1_function: function() {
    console.log("This is from base 1");
   }
  }
 );
 
 var Base_2 = custom.class(
  function() {
   
  },{
   base_2_function: function() {
    console.log("This is from base 2");
   }
  }
 );
 
 /*
  Derrived inherits properties, constants & functions from base_1 & base_2
  if anything is redeclared in Derrived, it is considered overloaded
  
  (When a new Derrived object is made, the constructors for base_1 & base_2 are called first)
 */
 var Derrived = custom.class_extends([Base_1,Base_2],
  function() {
   
  },{
   overloadedFunction: function() {
    console.log("This is from derrived");
   }
  }
 );
 
 onload = function() {
  var derrived = new Derrived();
  
  derrived.base_1_function();
  derrived.base_2_function();
  derrived.overloadedFunction();
 }
 
}();
```